# How to set default HTTP header in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I know how to set headers for a single HTTP call using the [Headers class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Headers-class.html).

Is there a way to do it for **all** HTTP calls?

Answer (score 13):

I see two ways to do that:

- **Option #1**: use the `BaseRequestOptions` class

You could extend this class and set the header to use for each request:

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions{
    headers:Headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
}
```

And registers it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide( RequestOptions, { useClass: DefaultRequestOptions })
});
```

- **Option #2**: extend the `Http` class itself

You could also extend the `Http` class and set the headers you want in it, as described below:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options);        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    // Add headers into options
    (...)
    return super.get(url, options);
  }

  (...)
}
```

And registers it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(Http, {
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Is there a way we can modify the return observable within the service. Like changing what happens when the request is started or finished? How will we do that?

Comment: In short can we modify the observable that is returned?

Comment: With option 2, here's comprehensive guide on adding default http headers (and catch http errors ) by extending the Http class - http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

Comment: Option #1 - updated for the current Angular release - is a much easier approach if headers (and other request options) are your concern. The official Angular docs recommend it (the [HTTP guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options) will say so in a few days).

Full request and response interception is another matter. There is a doc for that purpose in the wings. Stay tuned (Jan 2017-ish).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use someting like `$httpProvider` for angular1 but you can create your own `CustomHttp` class which extends/wraps the default `Http` and add your headers.

Take a look at `AuthHttp` source code from `angular2-jwt` library:
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/angular2-jwt.ts