# How to handle ajaxStart and ajaxStop events in Angular2 way

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular2-http

I need to trigger similar to JQuery events **ajaxStart** and **ajaxStop**
I found a half solution here ->
[How to set default HTTP header in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969292/how-to-set-default-http-header-in-angular2/34969367#34969367)
So, at the moment i can handle an `ajaxStart` Event.

Any solutions how to handle `ajaxStop` event?

```
post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    //onAjaxStart
    $( "#loader" ).show();
    return super.post(url, body, options); //Any method here to handle event?
}
```

I tried to use `.catch()`, but it fires only onError

I need to call my animate loader when ajax fires, and hide it when it stops every time i use ajax request.

So i am trying to override default ajax methods. But i can't find right observable method(

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but instead of using jQuery why don't you have an if statement on the elements and show/hide them based on a variable inside of your Component? I think that's generally the Angular way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the "finally" operator of observable.

Here is a sample of use:

```
post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    //onAjaxStart
    $( "#loader" ).show();
    return super.post(url, body, options).finally(() => {
      //onAjaxStop
      $( "#loader" ).hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah its cool, but i need to return an oservable object. 

Because i want to call this overrided method as simple post/get/etc request

Yeah its cool, but i need to return an oservable object. 

Because i want to call this overrided method as simple post/get/etc request


      this.http.post("someult", string).map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe().....etc

Comment: This doesn't prevent from regarding the observable ;-) I mean the one returned by the finally method. When subscribing on it you will receive the result of the request...