# Ionic2 Default http headers

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am following this one here [How do I set default Http Headers for all requests in Ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632928/how-do-i-set-default-http-headers-for-all-requests-in-ionic-2)

This works fine and in all http calls it pass the headers I put.
But my problem is when I inject any service to this MyRequestOptions constructor this service is undefined and cant use it...

Anyone know why? I need to inject here my custom AuthService to also put the JWT token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `BaseReqestOptions` uses `@Injectable`, which cases the `BaseRequestOptions` constructor to be called instead of your subclass constructor. So you could either:

***Use a factory***

```
providers: [{
  provide: RequestOptions,
  deps: [ Config ],
  useFactory: (config: Config) => {
    return new DefaultRequestOptions(config);
  }
}]
```

This will allow you to create the service yourself, without Angular trying to inject it. Or you could

***Extend `RequestOptions` instead***

```
@Injectable()
class DefaultRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor(public config: Config) {
    super({method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: new Headers()})

    this.headers.append('data', this.config.data);
  }
}
```

`RequestOptions` isn't decorated with `@Injectable`. And if you look at [the source code for BaseRequestOptions](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L180), you see all it does is the same thing we are doing above (with the `super` call).

> I need to inject here my custom AuthService to also put the JWT token

You need to be careful with this if `AuthService` is injecting `Http`. You might get a circular dependency error (because `Http` uses `RequestOptions` and your `RequestOptions` needs `Http`). One way to handle this is to inject the `Injector`, instead `Http` into the service. Then just `get` the `Http` from the `Injector`.