# Angular2 RC5 Default http headers

Tags: angular

There was possibility to extend Http or BaseRequestOptions in RC4
and add default headers to all http requests.
Like here [How to set default HTTP header in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969292/how-to-set-default-http-header-in-angular2)
How to do it in RC5 ?

Found `export declare function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions): Http;` in http.d.ts line 163. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You still can use CustomRequestOptions just like in RC4:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: CustomRequestOptions}) ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})


import { Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

export class CustomRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
    merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            options.headers = headers;
            var result = super.merge(options);
            result.merge = this.merge;
            return result;
        }
        return super.merge(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: What `import` to `provide`, in `providers: [provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: CustomRequestOptions}) ]`?